# Jquery slider. On Slider Stop raise server side event

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

i would like to raise a server side event at the mouseup event of the jquery slider.
How can i accomplish this? Can you point me a good place to start?

The server side code i would like to call is

```
Private Sub LoadBlock(ByVal AA As Integer)
'A lot of stuff here
End Sub
```

The value gathered from the Jquery slider event should be passed as a parameter in the procedure above

My current JQuery is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var Country = ['<% =String.Join("', '", arrayString)%>'];

        $('#slider-range-max').slider({
            max: '<%= arrayLength%>',
            min: 0,
            value: '<%= iValue%>',
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                var splitValues = Country[ui.value].split("~");
                $('#lblGame').html(splitValues[0]);
                $('#hpHome').html(splitValues[1]);
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) { }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Finally this is not a homework!!!

Comment: `ajax` might be the one you are looking for.

Comment: Do you want to call webmethod or any method behind page?

Comment: I would like to call any non static method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have tested this code but certainly this will help you

take one button

```
<asp:Button ID="img_update" runat="server" Text="Submit" style='display:none' OnClick="img_update_Click" />
```

your method non-static method

```
 protected void img_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//your code -behind
    }
```

Now your jquery will looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var Country = ['<% =String.Join("', '", arrayString)%>'];

        $('#slider-range-max').slider({
            max: '<%= arrayLength%>',
            min: 0,
            value: '<%= iValue%>',
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                var splitValues = Country[ui.value].split("~");
                $('#lblGame').html(splitValues[0]);
                $('#hpHome').html(splitValues[1]);
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                 document.getElementById('client id of button').click();
               }
        });
    });

</script>
```

I hope this will give you better idea how to implement non-static method regards.....:)

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var Country = ['<% =String.Join("', '", arrayString)%>'];

        $('#slider-range-max').slider({
            max: '<%= arrayLength%>',
            min: 0,
            value: '<%= iValue%>',
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                var splitValues = Country[ui.value].split("~");
                $('#lblGame').html(splitValues[0]);
                $('#hpHome').html(splitValues[1]);
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
            //bof:AJAX hit
            var path="YourPageName.aspx/NewMethod";
            $.ajax({
                url:path,type:"POST",cache:"false",
                dataType:"json",contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data:"{'str1':'Some Temp String'}",
                success:function(response){alert("response is "+response.d);
                },error:function(){
                }
            });
            //eof:AJAX hit
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

and in code behind:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod> _
Public Shared Function NewMethod(str1 As String) As String
'make same name of variable as in json data
    'do your server side stuff
    Return "Success"
End Function
```

Comment: Do not forget to activate page methods aswell.